# Код выдаёт ошибку, не понимаю что не так

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Бот должен отправлять мемы, но выдаётся ошибка-не могу понять как её исправить

Вот код:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import telebot
import datetime

bot = telebot.TeleBot("---------------------")
channel_id = -----------------
print(bot.get_me())
url = "https://dtf.ru/kek/entries/new"
header = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.90 Safari/537.36"
}

while True:
    def meme():
        r = requests.get(url, headers=header).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
        bs = soup.find('div', class_='content-image')
        bs2 = bs.find('div', class_='andropov_image')
        list = open("list.txt", "w+")
        link = (bs2['data-image-src'])
        if link not in list:
            with open("list.txt", "w") as file:
                file.write(link)
                bot.send_photo(channel_id, link)
                print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Отправил")
        else:
            print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Новых мемов пока нет")
    meme()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Ошибка:[image: ошибка]

Был бы рад если подскажите как исправить ошибку

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Попробуй `bot.send_photo(chat_id=channel_id, photo=link)`

Comment: А еще рекомендую переименовать переменную `list` ибо она зарезервированная переменная, и это может вызвать ошибки `_list = open("list.txt", "w+")`

Comment: Ошибка исправлена, спасибо
Но вот всё ещё выдаёт `{'ok': False, 'error': 'Got unexpected response. (404) - {"ok":false,"error_code
":404,"description":"Not Found"}'}` Как мне это исправить?